# Arduino Micro disappears on osX 10.11.6

Tags: serial, usb, arduino-micro, osx

so I have an arduino micro, and it was working fine until the latest security update for OSX 10.11.6 now the port won't show up in the arduino IDE. This doesn't seem to be a problem with the Uno / Huzzah / Mega or Makey Makey, but the port shows up when the micro is booting up, then disappears when the boot is done.

Anyone else having this issue? I've googled and found something about signed ktels. I've also installed some extra FTDI drivers, but no dice. Cord is fine, and works w/ other devices.

Suggestions?

Thanks!

Comment: Please, accept your own answer to close the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it. It was a weird timing thing, and I had to hit reset as the sketch was uploading. Seems to be fine now.